# Соревнование: Как создать переменную без оператора `=`, Python

Tags: python, соревнование

### Соревнование:

Требуется написать код на Python, после выполнения которого такая строка кода выведет `50`:

```py
print(test)
```

Вывод:

> 50

При этом запрещается использовать *оператор* `=` в **своём коде**. Любые сторонние методы приветствуются.

Ещё одно условие: один способ - один ответ. Допускается публикация нескольких способов от одного участника, но в разных ответах.

### Формат ответа

---

"Описание (если есть)"

```py
# "Действия"

print(test)  # В основной части кода
```

"Пояснения (если есть)"

---

### Критерий победы

Самое большое количество голосов по состоянию на **15.12.2022**.

#### Приз победителя:

Его ответ будет принят (т.е. +15 репутации).

Comment: `print(test:=50)` :)

Comment: @splash58 Да так тоже можно 

Comment: На сайте множество примеров с `globals()/locals()`.

Comment: а зачем эти извращения ? в пеп8 ведь сказано "Явное лучше, чем неявное"

Comment: Кстати никто до сих пор не нашел моего решения!

Comment: Я добавил ещё вариант )

Comment: @CrazyElf Опять не тот!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что в данный момент не соревнование, а угадайка "догадайтесь как я решил эту задачу". По оформлению соревнований смотрите см. справку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/code-golf

Comment: @NickolayChistov Есть вопрос. Оборачивать `print(test)` можно в другие конструкции или это должна быть последняя строка кода и без отступов? Судя по одному из ответов - можно, в этом случае я добавил ещё вариант.

Comment: @insolor Да ладно, прикольно же ))

Comment: @CrazyElf не вижу ничего прикольного. Вопрос нужно закрыть как слишком общий, на общих основаниях, либо привести в соответствие с правилами по соревнованиями.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Если правильно понимаю, строка кода с принтом должна быть отдельной.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin "недоумение" не в том, что ответ не удалён, а в том, что он БЫЛ опубликован, а голос за закрытие НЕ БЫЛ отозван. Удаление ответа уже ничего в этом плане не меняет, поэтому мне было интересно услышать причину. Публикация ответа в виде комментария так же не проясняет ситуацию, это всё равно ответ, хоть и данный не общепринятым путём. То есть подход "голосую за закрытие и одновременно даю ответ" по-прежнему не очевиден. Поэтому просьба [опубликовать ответ на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4957/176217) остаётся в силе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Класс и метакласс:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return '50'

class test(object, metaclass=Meta):
    pass

print(test)
```

2. Класс и подмена функции `print`

```
from sys import stdout

class test:
    pass

print = lambda x: stdout.write('50')
print(test)
```

3. `try-except`, правда в этом случае переменная вообще не создаётся, но вывод ожидаемый:

```
try:
    print(test)
except:
    print(50)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for test in range(50,51):
  print(test)
```

Comment: это не совсем то: после выполнения которого такая строка кода выведет 50`

Comment: @splash58 ну да, я уже когда отправил, то сообразил

Comment: @splash58 хотя почему же. После этого кода строчка ``print(test)`` выведет 50. Но можно ее и на break заменить, например. Или на continue.

Answer (score 3):

Например, так:

Создать новый файл, в нем создать переменную, а потом импортировать его и вытащить его так:

```py
print(your_file.your_variable)
```

Comment: А как-нибудь по другому сможете, я смог.

Comment: @AnGeL0ChEk, эта куча скобок после `...50)` не нужна

Comment: создать новый файл, в нем создать переменную, а потом импортировать его и выташить его так print(your_file.your_variable)

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```python
exec("test = 50")
print(test)
```

Формально сам оператор `=` не используется.

Answer (score 2):

И вот так тоже можно:

```py
globals().__setitem__('test', 50)

print(test)
```

Comment: А, ну да, записать в globals это самое очевидное. Но как-то не сообразил ))